# How to restrict datetimepicker to weekdays and save it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I need to know  how am I able to restrict datetimepicker to weekdays, so the user can only select days from Monday to Friday.

Since now it is only displaying the weekday as inserted in Custom Format (DateTimePicker Properties) an I will also need it to only save the "name" of the days of the week and not the whole field with time and day/month/year.

Thank you

Comment: If you arent saving anything but the DayOfWeek, just use a combo with weekday names in it.  A DTP seem like overkill

Comment: @Plutonix I think that I´m going to follow your advice, since it would actually be easier in this way. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @Plutonix, better use Combo Box.